# Redirect not Redirecting

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an entry in Web.config under `<system.webServer>`:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.mydomain.com*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

I expect that requests to `http://www.mydomain.com` will be redirected to `https://www.mydomain.com`.  However, this is not happening.

Is there something wrong with the format of the rule?  Must something else be done as well to enable the redirect?

This is running on a Windows 2012 machine under IIS 8.  RewriteModule is listed under Modules for that website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `"(.mydomain.com*)"` and set it to `"(.*)"`

```
<rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
    </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Same behavior after that change.

Comment: @EricJ. Try this one. Sorry for my previous answer.

Comment: That did it!  Any idea why though?  The previous pattern was also matched.

Comment: @EricJ. I remembered I had the config file of an old project. Not really :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the IIS Rewrite Module (installable using the [Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx) is installed. Then, you can use IIS Manager to [see, configure, and test the rewrite rules](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/testing-rewrite-rule-patterns).

EDIT: I noticed you said you verified the module is installed. Cool! Most likely it's a problem with the rule itself. Use the testing tools provided by IIS to verify it works the way you expect.

EDIT 2: I think the problem with your rule was your match URL syntax. According to http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference#Rule_pattern_syntax, the default syntax is ECMAScript regular expressions. That means if you want to match the `.` character you'd have to use `\.`.

Comment: Sorry, edited in late that RewriteModule is installed.  I'll check out the link on managing the rewrite rules now.

Comment: When I enter the test pattern www.mydomain.com, it tells me that the input URL matches the pattern.  Still, it is not redirecting.